# Auto-scrobble video titles

Tags: c++

I want to automate the service myshows.ru. Riht now, people must manually input information about movies they watched.

I want to write a program in c++, that gets the titles of movies in video players and scrobbles them to their account on the service.

What libraries I can use for this work?

Comment: Is there any special reason why you choose to do this in c++?

Comment: Determining the video title from the media player window title is probably a **bad idea**. What if someone uses another media player ? Or if the media player you use as a reference suddenly changes the way the title is displayed ?

Comment: Only one reason - I am learning language

Comment: Yes, I know about this problems and for this reason I was searching solution on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plain Winapi functions paired with some regex library. What you have to do is to enumerate windows in your system (get their `HWND` - handles), then take their captions and store them in `std::strings`. The next step would be checking if your caption matches some regex (this could be `boost::regex` or `boost::xpressive`, for example) - so you would have to maintain a regex database for every possible multimedia player caption.

There is a more complicated approach that is harder to code, but which is more efficient. The number of players that are widely used isn't very big, therefore you can enumerate processes in your system using Winapi call and take only players (like `mpc.exe` or `winamp.exe`). Then you can easily retrieve the active application window (from it's process handle) and only then invoke your regex search. This is actually much better, because you would only have to store `process name - caption regex` values in your database.

After that (when you've parsed out the name of currently opened file), it's all up to you - I mean storing it at the server, etc, etc.

Comment: what? was this meant for stackoverflow.ru?

Comment: haven't heard about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? :-)

Comment: =D Well, I actually thought that if the person who asked this is bad in english, it would be ok if I translate everything, especially if I can...

Comment: Big thx to you! Now I know what should I do. Thanks for translation to russian, but I have problems only with english grammar.